# DRY a Rails AJAX Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, dry

I'm running Rails 4 and have a few AJAX Requests. I've gotten them to run and they are working well. However, what I've found is that these many different requests have very, very similar `js.erb` files.

What is the best way to DRY my `js.erb` calls? Is there a way to simply have one and call it through the `format.js` response?

`js.erb`:

```
$("#overview").html("<%= j(render partial: 'profiles/show/overview') %>");
$("#profile").html("<%= j(render partial: 'profiles/show/profile') %>");
$("#interactions").html("<%= j(render partial: 'profiles/show/interactions') %>");
$("#actions").html("<%= j(render partial: 'profiles/show/actions') %>");

var accordionBody = $('.accordion > .accordion-container > .accordion-body'),
  accordionTitleTarget = $('.accordion > .accordion-container > .accordion-title > a');

if ($('.accordion').length) {
  accordionBody.hide();
}

accordionTitleTarget.on('click', accordionOnClick);

provisional_rating();
ready();
```

`ready` and `provisional-rating` are functions defined in `application.js`

Comment: Its tough to say without knowing more precisely what they have in common?

Comment: Sorry, let me add an example

Comment: What's the part that differs?

Comment: All of the `js.erb` are the same. The controller methods are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render the same view each time, you can render it explicitly:

```
format.js { render action: "profiles/show/action.js.erb" }
```

You will need to set any instance variables beforehand, but that will also allow you to customize the render for each action.